# Undefined Reference to global static function

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

Inside the header file there is the following:

```
Context.h:
namespace kgl
{
  namespace vk
  {
    /** Function to initialize the rendering library
     */ 
    static void initialize() ;

    /** Function to retrieve whether or not the rendering library is initialized.
     * @return Whether or not the rendering library is initialized.
     */
    static bool isInitialized() ;

    /** Function to shut down rendering library.
     */
    static void shutdown() ;

    /** Function to retrieve the vulkan instance for this program.
     */
    static const ::vk::Instance instance() ;
    ...
    ...
```

And then, in the cpp file I have:

```
Context.cpp:
namespace kgl
{
  namespace vk
  {
    static VulkanContextData vk_context ;

    const ::vk::Instance instance()
    {
      return ::kgl::vk::vk_context.instance.instance() ;
    }

    void initialize()
    {
      ::kgl::vk::vk_context.initialize() ;
    }

    bool isInitialized()
    {
      return ::kgl::vk::vk_context.initialized ;
    }

    void shutdown()
    {
      ::kgl::vk::vk_context.shutdown() ;
    } 
    ...
    ...
```

When I link this library in an executable 'undefined reference to kgl::vk::instance()' linker error.

If i remove this one usage:

```
  Window.cpp:
  void Window::initialize( const char* name, unsigned gpu, unsigned width, unsigned height )
  { 
    const ::vk::Instance instance = ::kgl::vk::instance() ;

    data().window = SDL_CreateWindow( name, 500, 500, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ) ;
    ...
    ...
```

It builds just fine. vk::Instance comes from vulkan.hpp which the vulkan libraries provide, and I do forward declare it inside Context.h. However, I do this with every vulkan object, and this is the only problem I am having with building.

Comment: Do you know what `static` means, when used on functions? Why do you think, that you need it?

Comment: Which function is not found, please provide error message!

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius oops, that is the issue. I'm just used to placing global functions in the same file they are defined, heh. Thank you!